# Ordenação crescente e decrecente no ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

Tenho que ordenar o `clientdataset` por 3 campos ao mesmo tempo:

1 - Ativo(0 ou 1)
2 - data(dd/mm/yyyy)
3 - nome

O problema é que preciso fazer ordenações diferentes para cada um deles, o 1º decrescente e os outros crescentes.

Existe um modo de fazer isso no `clientdataset` ou será necessária alguam outra abordagem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Basta utilizar os indices oferecidos pelo DataSet.

Acho interessante abordar um pouco sobre os indices:

Existem básicamente dois tipos de indices no Delphi: Os **temporários** e os **persistentes**.

Indices **temporários** são criados utilizando o IndexFieldNames. Vamos supor que você tenha um ClientDataSet com os fields: PrimeiroNome, UltimoNome e DataNascimento. Se eu quiser ordenar meus registros Pelo último nome e depois pelo primeiro, eu poderia fazer isso:

```
ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'UltimoNome;PrimeiroNome';
```

A qualquer tempo isso pode ser alterado.

```
ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'UltimoNome';  
// etc...
```

Quando você faz isso o delphi cria os indices internamente e os associa ao dataset. Por isso são chamados **temporários**.

No seu caso isso não lhe atenderá, escrevi apenas para enriquecimento. No seu caso um índice **persistente** será mais adequado:

Índices **persistentes** são criados no IndexDefs de seu DataSet. Assim você pode, para cada índice, definir uma série de propriedades. São utilizados da mesma forma que os índices **temporários**, bastando utilizar o nome dado ao índice **persistente** quando os mesmos forem criados em design-time.

Para criar um Índice **Persistente** em RunTime, basta utilizar o trecho de código abaixo:

```
with ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do 
begin 
  Name := 'OrdenarUltimoPrimeiroNomedx'; 
  Fields := 'UltimoNome;PrimeiroNome';
  Options := [ixDescending, ixCaseInsensitive]; 
end; 
ClientDataSet1.IndexName := 'OrdenarUltimoPrimeiroNomedx';
```

EDIT: Falei tanto e acabei não dando uma resposta exata.

Você pode criar quantos índices persistentes precisar:

```
with ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do 
begin 
  Name := 'OrdenarUltimoPrimeiroNomedx'; 
  Fields := 'UltimoNome;PrimeiroNome';
  Options := [ixDescending, ixCaseInsensitive]; 
end; 

with ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do 
begin 
  Name := 'DataNascimentoAscdx'; 
  Fields := 'DataNascimento';
  Options := [ixAscending]; 
end; 

ClientDataSet1.IndexName := 'DataNascimentoAscdx;OrdenarUltimoPrimeiroNomedx';
```

No exemplo acima eu vou ordenar pela data de nascimento Ascendente e depois pelo Ultimo Nome e Primeiro Nome Descendente.

Caso queira uma boa referência, sugiro que acesse este [link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056):

Comment: Obrigado. Só faltou explicar como conseguir ordenar uns campos na ordem crescente e outros como decrescente. contudo com sua explicação consegui fazer aqui.
Seguindo seu ultimo Exemplo, caso eu queira que ordene o sobrenome por ordem decrescente, mas o nome em ordem crescente, ficaria assim:
<!-- language: lang-delphi -->
    with ClientDataSet1.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do 
    begin 
      Name := 'OrdenarNomedx'; 
      Fields := 'UltimoNome;PrimeiroNome';
      descFields := 'UltimoNome'
      Options := [ixDescending]; 
    end; 
    ClientDataSet1.IndexName := 'OrdenarNomedx';

Comment: @Stribus realmente eu poderia dar uma atençã a isto. Editei a resposta para deixar mais claro como resolver seu problema. Obrigado pelo toque.

Comment: Cara, parabéns, foi ótima, precisa e satisfatória sua resposta.

Comment: Options := [ixAscending]; Não aceita essa propiedade!

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da versão do Delphi que você tenha pode fazer assim:

```
ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'UltimoNome:D;PrimeiroNome';
```

a instrução ':D' indica que é em ordem descendente, se deixar sem nada o cds entende que é Ascendente. Se no teu Delphi não funcionar, então utilize o índice persistente.

Comment: Delphi XE3 não funcionou.